# GCC `scanf` segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, struct, scanf

I was playing around with C and the `scanf` function and came across this weird error that I can't seem to figure out. Given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int a;
} sample;

void fn(sample *s) {
  char command;
  scanf("%[abc]", &command);
  printf("Read: %c\n", command);
  printf("In the sample function:, %i\n", s->a);
}

int main() {
  sample *s = malloc(sizeof(sample));
  s->a = 4;

  printf("Before sample function: %i\n", s->a);
  fn(s);
  printf("After sample function: %i\n", s->a);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems to seg fault. With the output:

```
$ ./sample
Before sample function: 4
a
Read: a
In the sample function:, 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I used gdb and attached a `watch` to the struct, it seems that inside the `scanf` function, it seems to 'modify' the struct? Which is weird, because even after the `scanf` inside the sample function '`fn`', it is able to print out the struct fields fine. However, once returning from the `fn` and jumping back into `main`, it seg faults when it tries to print out the same information?

Interestingly, if you change the `scanf` to `scanf("%c\n", &command);` (without the character set) it seems to work fine. For the record, the version of gcc I am using is 4.7.2, and I am compiling the code with: `gcc -O0 -o sample sample.c`.

My only thought is that perhaps character sets aren't supported by gcc? I'm not sure. Just wondering if anyone else could clear this up?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
it works with gcc -O0 -o sample sample.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf("%[abc]", &command);`

writes a string not a single character. The trailing null character of the string is being written in `&command + 1` in your program.

You should pass to `scanf` something like:

`command` with `command` being:

```
char command[2];
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you! That makes so much sense actually. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: You're welcome! Also be careful that if you pass more than one character to `scanf` you will overflow your buffer. To do error recovery, you should look to `fgets` with `sscanf` rather than `scanf`.

Comment: Just another quick question if you don't mind, is there any reason why it would work on other versions of GCC or clang?

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior and as undefined is undefined, it may work on Saturday but fails on Monday.

Comment: You should also use `scanf("%1[abc]", &command)` to limit the string to a single character, so it won't overflow the 2-character buffer...